# How to re-install Linux Mint 12?

Tags: installation, linux-mint

I have dual booted my Windows XP installing the CD version of Linux Mint 12. And then I upgraded it to the DVD version. I am having many errors on my PC, so I would like to re-install the CD version of Linux Mint 12.

How to do it? Do I have to remove Linux Mint and re-install it? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Mint again you choose to make partitions. This means that all data is erased so you will have fresh Mint installation.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install XP boot sector (FIXMBR / FIXBOOT) That will wipe trails of Mint from XP boot process.

I'd install VirtualBox with Linux first just to get comfortable before doing bigger installation.

You can use boot.ini to boot 2nd partition (ask google for linux and boot.ini)
Or install some boot manager with one-sector bootmgr of freebsd probably being te smallest (asking for 1s to boot other partition, otherwise resorting to previously booted)